# Heroku somehow almost doubled slug size

Tags: python, heroku

"Compiled slug size: 1G is too large (max is 500M)" is the error we are getting when we make changes to our main github branch, which is monitored by our deployment app and supposed to automatically build. We have gotten the "slug size too large" error in the past, but it wasn't as big as 1G before. I have tried running the "du -ha --max-depth 1 /app | sort -hr" command and this was the output:

> 628M /app 416M /app/.heroku 212M /app/source 72K /app/users 44K
> /app/config 20K /app/docs 16K /app/.profile.d
> 8.0K /app/README.md
> 8.0K /app/.github
> 4.0K /app/startup.sh
> 4.0K /app/.slugignore
> 4.0K /app/runtime.txt
> 4.0K /app/requirements.txt
> 4.0K /app/pytest.ini
> 4.0K /app/Procfile
> 4.0K /app/manage.py
> 4.0K /app/.gitignore

Our Dependencies are:

```
Django==3.1.12
Pillow==8.2.0
boto3==1.11.12
django-allauth==0.42.0
django-crispy-forms==1.9.1
django-environ==0.4.5
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-storages==1.9.1
gunicorn==20.0.4
psycopg2==2.8.6
mixer==6.1.3
pytest==5.4.3
social-auth-app-django==4.0.0
```

I have cleared the cache of our deployment app (not the production one) and I got the same result trying to build and also when running the "du -ha --max-depth 1 /app | sort -hr" command. We also get the message "Process exited with status 130" when looking through the logs. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Also got a message from Heroku that our slug size is 308MB, although I tried running the build again and still have the same error.

Comment: Your slug doesn't just contain your Python code; it contains all of your dependencies and your language runtime, too. What are you depending on?

Comment: If you're asking what my dependencies are they are these: Django==3.1.12
Pillow==8.2.0
boto3==1.11.12
django-allauth==0.42.0
django-crispy-forms==1.9.1
django-environ==0.4.5
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-storages==1.9.1
gunicorn==20.0.4
psycopg2==2.8.6
mixer==6.1.3
pytest==5.4.3
social-auth-app-django==4.0.0

Comment: Please [edit] that into your question. But all of those dependencies, and all of _their_ dependencies, need to be included in your slug. They take up space.

Comment: Ok I have added that into my original question. I also added in that I just got a message from heroku that our slug size is 308MB and to try and run the build again, however we still get the same error. I think my main source of confusion is that we used to get that slug size error and everything still worked fine, but now for some reason it doesn't.